# How to translate the value of %a given by printf?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double-precision

What is the value of `0x1.921fb82c2bd7fp+1` in a human readable presentation?
I got this value by `printf` using `%a`.

Comment: If you can't read that, use `%f` to get a decimal representation of 3.141592999999999857863031138549558818340301513671875.

Comment: @DanielFischer How can I read that? what is the structure of this value?

Comment: Read up on it [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/)

Comment: Read the value with `scanf()` and `%a`; format it with `printf()` and `%g` (or `%e` or `%f`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mantissa is hexadecimal and the exponent is a decimal value representing the power of 2 the mantissa is scaled by.

Comment: Also note that the 1 before the decimal point is not stored in the double. It is inferred from the fact that the number is in the normalized range.